# Find MAX in a dynamic range and repeat the code for the rest of the data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that can already find the max of time for a set of material number, but is stuck to repeat the code to the next sets of material number. Pls refer below for the table of data and the code.

The material number change from **1001, 1002, 1003..** the material number will not be in sequence.
The rows to be considered are for process **a** until **h** only.
**a.1,a.2,h.1** and **h.2** need to be excluded from the max value range.

The code below also will only take the 1st max in case of repeating max value.
Pls advise on how to repeat the code for the rest of the material numbers and to take only the range of process **a-h**. Possibly if we can refer to the process as some ranges might have additional/less processes.

**Sample Data:**

```
Material    Process   Time (mins)
1001          a.1        0.00
1001          a.2        0.00
1001          a          0.50
1001          b          0.70
1001          c          1.00
1001          d          2.50
1001          e          1.00
1001          f          0.30
1001          g          0.50
1001          h          0.90
1001          h.1        0.00
1001          h.2        0.00
1002          a.1        0.00
1002          a.2        0.00
1002          a          0.40
1002          b          0.60
1002          c          1.00
1002          d          2.00
1002          e          2.00
1002          f          0.30
1002          g          0.80
1002          h          0.50
1002          h.1        0.00
1002          h.2        0.00
```

**Sample End Result:**

```
Material    Process   Time (mins)
1001          a.1        0.00
1001          a.2        0.00
1001          a          0.00
1001          b          0.00
1001          c          0.00
1001          d          2.50
1001          e          0.00
1001          f          0.00
1001          g          0.00
1001          h          0.00
1001          h.1        0.00
1001          h.2        0.00
1002          a.1        0.00
1002          a.2        0.00
1002          a          0.00
1002          b          0.00
1002          c          0.00
1002          d          2.00
1002          e          0.00
1002          f          0.00
1002          g          0.00
1002          h          0.00
1002          h.1        0.00
1002          h.2        0.00
```

**Current Code:**

```
Sub test()

Dim LastRowB As String
Dim LastRowC As Long
Dim VarC As Double
Dim i As Integer
Dim varMAX as Double

LastRowB = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

VarC = Range("C4").Value

For i = 2 To LastRowC
   If Range("C" & i).Value > VarC Then
       VarC = Range("C" & i).Value
   End If
Next i

For i = 2 To LastRowC
   If Range("C" & i).Value < VarC Then
       Range("C" & i).Value = 0
   End If
Next i

varMax = 0
For i = 2 To LastRowC
 If Range("C" & i).Value < VarC Then
      Range("C" & i).Value = 0
  Else
      If Range("C" & i).Value = VarC And varMax < 1 Then
       varMax = varMax + 1
   Else
       Range("C" & i).Value = 0
   End If
 End If
 Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the output?

Comment: @PJ Rosenburg the output will change all the other time to zero except the first max value. i need to do a mass change data for the materials available. i have tried recording a macro (using if function) but the range is not flexible. the process may differ according to material numbers.

Comment: @PJ Rosenburg thanks for the help :) the end result is i need to maintain the table of processes instead of only the max process and time visible in the Result sheet. i still need to have the process a.1 - h.2 available only the max time will be shown and other time is change to zero.

Comment: @PJ Rosenburg sorry for the confusion. i edited my question with the sample end result, if u can have a look?

Comment: See the revised answer, I think we have a winner.

Comment: @PJ Rosenburg it is a winner! u are godsent. thanks very much :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is revised based on comments above:

This keeps the original sheet, Goes through and sets Column C values to 0 if they aren't = to the max value.  If there is more than one process per material with the max value, they will both print. 
I know that the materials will not be in sequence, but your example does have them sorted by material, and the code requires them to be sorted like your example.

**TESTED:**

```
Sub test()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim tempMaterial As String
Dim newMaterial As String
Dim tempProcess As String

Dim VarC As Double
Dim tRow As Long                'Used for Result - Can Remove
Dim tempMaxRow As Long
Dim tempMinRow As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

sheetName = "Sheet1"            'Set SheetName here
VarC = 0
tempMaterial = ""
tempMinRow = 2

'Begin loop through sheet.  If the materials don't match, 
'go back and rewrite "C" values for last Material

For lRow = 2 To LastRow + 1
    newMaterial = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lRow, 1).Text
    If tempMaterial <> newMaterial And tempMaterial <> "" Then
        tempMaxRow = lRow - 1
        If tempMaxRow > 2 Then
            For r = tempMinRow To tempMaxRow     'Go through temp range of material
                If Sheets(sheetName).Cells(r, 3) < VarC Then
                    Sheets(sheetName).Cells(r, 3) = 0
                End If
            Next r
        End If

        'Set the new temp Material & Reset the Max Variable
        tempMaterial = newMaterial
        VarC = 0
        highProcess = ""
        tempMinRow = lRow

    End If

    'This gets done regardless of new material
    tempProcess = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lRow, 2).Text
    If Len(tempProcess) = 1 Then                                'Make sure process only has one letter
        If ProcessCheck(tempProcess) = True Then                'Check to see if it's A-H
            If Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lRow, 3) > VarC Then     'Check against Max value
                tempMaterial = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lRow, 1) 'Set Temp Material
                VarC = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lRow, 3)         'Set new max if greater than old
            End If
        End If
    End If

Next lRow

End Sub
```

**CHECK TO SEE IF PROCESS FALLS WITHIN RANGE OF A-H:**

```
Function ProcessCheck(process As String) As Boolean

Dim pass As Boolean

    pass = False

    If LetterToNumber(process) <= 8 Then    '8 is the numeric value of "H"
        pass = True
    End If

    ProcessCheck = pass

End Function
```

**CONVERT LETTER TO NUMBER:**

```
Function LetterToNumber(letter As String) As Long

Dim result As Long

    result = 0
    result = (Asc(UCase(Mid(letter, 1, 1))) - 64) + result * 26
    LetterToNumber = result

End Function
```

[image: Solution]

edit: Revised solution to solve OP